# how to define action link to action from controller in an area in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an area named customer. it contains a controller named customer with following action

```
public ActionResult BrowseByCategory(int id=0)
        {
            //some code here............
            return View();
        }
```

I need to create a link on for above action on the _layout.cshtml view on the root.

I have written following markup. but its not working

```
@Html.ActionLink(c.CategoryName, "BrowseByCategory", "Customer", new { area = "customer" },new { id = c.CategoryCode })
```

Please suggest the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505040#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) of `ActionLink` method that can be used in your case like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink(c.CategoryName, "BrowseByCategory", new { area = "customer", controller = "Customer", id = c.CategoryCode }, new { @* There should be htmlParameters *@ })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a model in an action in something as global as `_Layout.cshtml`, or at least you *shouldn't*. Technically, you *could* define a model for `_Layout.cshtml`, but then every... single.. view that uses this layout could only work with that same model. If you passed a different class type, you'd get runtime errors from your layout.

In your particular situation here, it seems that the link necessary in the layout is conditional on what category is currently being viewed. The best way to handle this, then, would be using sections.

In your layout, you can define a section like:

```
@RenderSection("CustomLink", required: false)
```

Just put that wherever you want the link to appear. Making it not required means you won't get runtime errors if some other view doesn't need this custom link.

Then, in your view:

```
@section CustomLink
{
    @Html.ActionLink(c.CategoryName, "BrowseByCategory", "Customer", new { area = "customer" },new { id = c.CategoryCode })
}
```

Now, this will appear where you want in your layout, but you can define it at the view level.